# R fulfill empty cells with previous values

Tags: r

I have database like this with two cols

1. c(1,na,na,2,na,3)
2. c(0,2,3,2,0,4)

And I want to get 1 column c(10,12,13,22,20,34)

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the first column contain blanks (`""`) and is `character` class, we convert the blanks to `NA` and use `na.locf` to replace the NA elements with the non-NA previous element, then `paste` the output with the second column and create a new column ("colN").

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[col1=="", col1:= NA][, colN := as.numeric(paste0(na.locf(col1), col2))]
df1
#   col1 col2 colN
#1:    1    0   10
#2:   NA    2   12
#3:   NA    3   13
#4:    2    2   22
#5:   NA    0   20
#6:    3    4   34
```

#### Update

Noticed the at the OP edited the post with the changes made on the first column i.e. now the blanks (`""`) got mysteriously changed to `na` (which is not a true NA).  In that case, while reading the dataset with `read.csv/read.table`, the `na.strings = "na"` can be used to automatically convert the "na" to `NA` or else

```
 setDT(df1)[col1=="na", col1 := NA][, colN := as.numeric(paste0(na.locf(col1, col2))]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("1", "", "", "2", "", "3"), col2 = c(0L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 4L)), .Names = c("col1", "col2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! =)